# Identify related tests for regression when a feature is changed

Tags: regression-testing

Would like to know if anyone has implemented a process on how to identify related test scripts for regression when a feature has changed.

Assuming that in BDD, one would group tests under a feature, I believe its not sufficient to run only the tests of that feature for Regression as there would be some other related feature that would have been impacted.

Technically is it possible for a tool like visual studio to guide on where the code in the Application has changed and recommend the tests from the regression pack ?

Comment: Are you reviewing the code so the effect is potentially transparent or looking at it from an opaque perspective? Based on the [Test Pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html) the change should have more unit tests and integration tests than UI tests if you're following TDD. Can you give an example of the change  -[mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it can be answered.

Comment: I have selenium BDD tests and so I am not talking about unit/integration tests. So its a Black box. I am aware of the Test pyramid, thanks. If a feature is altered, I was hoping visual studio would have some feature to recommend affected tests. But i cant find any information about this.

Comment: [code coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested) is the closest to what you want as far as I can tell if you're looking at the code as a Black box.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if that's the best approach. I will try to use code coverage however. Its surprising not many in the community is able to answer this question.